# Unable to view checkpoint paraquet files after operation in DBFS using Databricks Runtime Version 11.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I'm facing an issue with viewing checkpoint files in DBFS (Databricks File System) within my Deltalake environment over S3. According to my understanding, a checkpoint is supposed to be created for every 10th file, but I'm unable to see any checkpoint files even after performing more than 20 operations.

I'm using Databricks Runtime Version 11.0, which includes Apache Spark 3.3.0 and Scala 2.12.

Also I would like to know how can I view existing checkpoint settings?